# Need help my list comprehension python code

Tags: python, list

```
  students = ['Joe', 'Mary','Amy','Zach','Stan']
  awesome_students =['is awesome' for student in students]
  print(awesome_students)
```

Expected Output: 'Joe is awesome' 'Mary is awesome' 'Amy is awesome' etc

The output i get:  ['is awesome', 'is awesome' etc ]

Comment: write it out as a for loop, and then think how to apply the same logic inside the comprehsion

Comment: `student + ' is awesome'`…!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning a string literal `'is awesome'` instead of using your `student` variable.

One way of formatting the string with that variable is using a format string:

`awesome_students =[f'{student} is awesome' for student in students]`

Another is using the .format() string method

`awesome_students =['{} is awesome'.format(student) for student in students]`

Yet another, and probably the worst of all my suggestions, is concatenating them manually with the + operator:

`awesome_students =[student + ' is awesome' for student in students]`

Comment: hey thanks, I think the {student} is the best option

Comment: Yup. Presented in order of preference.

Comment: @new_be_0905 feel free to select this or the other answer as correct, so that others know what helped you.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code you need:

```
 students = ['Joe', 'Mary','Amy','Zach','Stan']
 awesome_students =[f"{student} is awesome" for student in students]
 print(awesome_students)
```

Before what you where doing was storing the string "is awesome" for every student in the list.

Comment: *f-strings* are good if there's a formatting, using it for simple strings concatenation is an overkill *(imho)*. Simple `+` will work:  `student + "is awesome"`

Comment: @OlvinRoght concatenation obfuscates formatting and punctuation. Your example is incorrect: `student + "is awesome"` should be `student + " is awesome"`, which is more obvious when it is one string `f'{student} is awesome'`

Comment: @jorf.brunning, I noticed that I missed space too late to edit, but I thought my message is pretty obvious. For beginners it's much easier to understand simple concatenation rather than investigate what does `f` prefix means and why variable name is surrounded by curly brackets. Also formatting consume more resources. I'm not against formatting, but same as any other feature it should be used on purpose.

Comment: I think an f string is something a beginner should learn, if he looks it up and learns what is does it could be good for learning. Nevertheless I think concatenation would also be a good way to do it.